# change column strptime() n data frame r

Tags: r

I have a column that I have already changed to DATE using as.date

```
> test_subset$Date <- as.Date(test_subset$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The next column holds numeric data as the times corresponding to adjacent column of dates. The problem I have is it keeps inserting the current date into this time only column - I specify column "TIME"

```
> test_subset[[2]] <- strptime(test_subset[[2]], "%H:%M:%S")
```

but the result appends the current date to the time.

1. How do I adjust the "TIME" column to NOT include the current date.
2. How can I strip out the current date from the "TIME" Column

Comment: I do understand that it should be inputting the current date as per the help file "For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."    I just do not know how to adjust the class without inputting the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is being inserted because you're using `strptime()`.  You can use `format()`, since you don't necessarily need a special class for the times.  If we have an example vector `x`,

```
x <- Sys.time() + 0:5
#[1] "2015-03-05 07:08:27 PST" "2015-03-05 07:08:28 PST"
#[3] "2015-03-05 07:08:29 PST" "2015-03-05 07:08:30 PST"
#[5] "2015-03-05 07:08:31 PST" "2015-03-05 07:08:32 PST"
```

To get the date only, you can use

```
as.Date(format(x, "%F"))
# [1] "2015-03-05" "2015-03-05" "2015-03-05" "2015-03-05"
# [5] "2015-03-05" "2015-03-05"
```

And to get the time only, use `format()` again, but with `%T`.

```
format(x, "%T")
# [1] "07:08:27" "07:08:28" "07:08:29" "07:08:30" "07:08:31"
# [6] "07:08:32"
```

If it turns out you **do** need a time class on the second column, you can use `chron::times()` which gives a "times" class.

```
(time <- chron::times(format(x, "%T")))
# [1] 07:08:27 07:08:28 07:08:29 07:08:30 07:08:31 07:08:32
class(time)
# [1] "times"
```

Comment: You rock that was so simple                                                              test_subset[[2]] <- format(test_subset[[2]], "%T")